# Replace preprocessor macro of string literal with concatenation

Tags: c++, c++17

I am attempting to replace as many uses of macros in our code with proper c++17 constructs. How would I replace the following macro with a constexpr or something else?

```
#define FNAME "first"
#define LNAME "last"
#define NAME FNAME LNAME
const char hello[] = "hello " NAME;
```

Comment: You can concatenate strings at compile-time, but if I were you, I'd create a small function that returns a static const string, generated the first time you call it.

Comment: it sounds simple, but parentheses also go a long way too when combining compile-time logic